# How to replace a specific html tag in bulk?

Tags: html, xml, read-more, blogger

I imported a Blogger XML to WordPress, but Blogger converts the tag `<!--more-->` into `<a name='more'></a>`, which is something that WordPress doesn't recognize as it should (I lost the *Read More* option).

How can I edit, maybe in plain text, and replace the old tag for the new one? Is there a "file", where I can see all posts and make this replacement?

Comment: The first part of your description seems backwards. What do you mean by "lost the read more option"? As for addressing conversion problems like this one, you could try a search and replace in your posts table (in the MySQL database). There are plugins to help with that if you don't know how to go about it. You can also achieve the same thing programmatically by filtering the post content. If your objective is to convert the blogger tag into a WordPress recognizable tag, you could try that. An alternative would be to write a script treating <a name... etc. like WP treats <!--more-->

Comment: Thank you! I edited the database and replaced the tag with notepad. It worked perfectly for all my posts!

Comment: Glad you worked it out!